# Panda Merging Unexpected Result

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes created with pandas. I don't know how to merge the two dataframes in a particular format using a common column.

I used

```
pd.merge(dataframe1,dataframe2,on='A',how='outer')
```

but that doesn't yield the expected result.

Expected Result:

```
dataframe 1:        dataframe 2:       Result:

A B                 A                   A B
0 1                 0                   0 1
1 0                 1                   1 0
2 0                 2                   2 0
4 1                 3                   3 Nan
                    5                   4 1
                                        5 Nan
```

Obtained Result:

```
dataframe 1:        dataframe 2:       Result:

A B                 A                   A B
0 1                 0                   0 1
1 0                 1                   1 0
2 0                 2                   2 0
4 1                 3                   3 1
                    5                   4 Nan
                                        5 Nan
```

Comment: I think your `how` parameter should be changed https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge

Comment: Your code actually works for me, but I have defined the data frame slightly different, please check my answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me, it's just that I defined the dataframes in a different way

```
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data1 = [[0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 0], [4,1]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['A', 'B'])
data2 = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [5]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['A'])
print(pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer', on='A'))
#   A    B
#0  0  1.0
#1  1  0.0
#2  2  0.0
#3  4  1.0
#4  3  NaN
#5  5  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

**Always check the data.** The used showed me that there were no spaces but then sent a file with spaces (He sent the version w/o hitting save) added `.str.strip()` to the data element and everything started working.

***Never trust any input. Always Verify.***

Comment: Once you eliminate all other options, the obvious problem is the most likely culprit.